# Android: Jsoup и AsyncTask

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Я пытаюсь парсить веб-сайт с помощью Jsoup в AsyncTask.

И дело в том, что почти всегда (примерно 4 раза из 5) выпадают исключительные ситуации.

Работает правильно редко(

Что с эти делать - не знаю.

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //publishProgress(new Void[] {});

         core();

        return info;

    }

     void core()
     {
         Elements links;

         if (today)
         {

             Document doc = null;
             try {
                 doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                 links = doc.select("table[class=translation]");
                 info =  links.outerHtml();

             }catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Log.e("errors","try-");
                 core();
             }

         }
     }
```

Лог выглядит так:

```
03-12 22:45:50.809: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:52.519: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:52.709: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:53.879: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:55.579: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:55.779: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
03-12 22:45:56.949: ERROR/errors(24683): try-
```

И т.д.
Полный вариант:

```
03-13 12:22:29.419: ERROR/errors(25804): try-
03-13 12:22:32.239: INFO/InputDispatcher(176): Delivering key to current input target
03-13 12:22:32.239: INFO/PowerManagerService(176): Ulight 3->7|0
03-13 12:22:32.319: INFO/InputDispatcher(176): Delivering key to current input target
03-13 12:22:32.509: WARN/System.err(25804): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
03-13 12:22:32.519: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
03-13 12:22:32.519: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
03-13 12:22:32.519: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:65)
03-13 12:22:32.519: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:225)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readLine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:660)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:690)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1040)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:412)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:101)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.529: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.539: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.core(ShowBar.java:110)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.doInBackground(ShowBar.java:81)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at com.parser.foot.ShowBar.doInBackground(ShowBar.java:23)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-13 12:22:32.549: WARN/System.err(25804): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-13 12:22:32.549: ERROR/errors(25804): try-
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Типичная ошибка начинающих прогеров - сразу начинать писать многотредном варианте. Вы сначала задачу отладьте без `AsyncTask` и потом когда убедитесь, что алгоритм работает верно начинайте его делить на многотредность.
2. Выведите получение коннекта из `doInBackground` или посадите под другой тред.